# Prevent Direct Access to inde.php via the browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I am making n alcoholic site that has a gateway for age verification wish is called default.html an it's in the root of my webspace. I have used Joomla which has two index files, one from the root folder and the other from the template that i am using. Now i know i can restrict direct access using .htaccess file but my question is should i put it in the root folder or in my templates folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a cookie in the gateway page, then check if it exists in the template's index file. So once you land on the gateway the cookie is set.

This is the code that sets the cookie

```
var theDate = new Date(); var oneYearLater = new Date(
theDate.getTime() + 31536000000       );    var expiryDate =
oneYearLater.toGMTString(); document.cookie =    "myTusker=tuskerUser;
expires=expiryDate;
```

Then in the templates index file i check if the cookie is set and if not, it redirects to the gateway page called default.php. Below is the code snippet.

```
$cookies = $_COOKIE;

if(!array_key_exists('myTusker', $cookies)) {

header("Location:http://zmbiz.net/tpfnew/default.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the `template` folder, then it's only considered when accessing that folder. So that's not the right place.

Put it in the root folder.

Comment: When i do that it doesn't work plus i read somewhere that i should not place it in the root folder. When i place it in the templates folder it works but it still fetches the content, modules and the components but the site is all messed up for it can't find the html and the style from the templates index file

Answer (score 0):

Joomla's model uses the index.php file in the site root, but if you block that the site won't work.

Have you looked in the [Content Restriction extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction) on the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)?

**EDIT**
I just has a look and found this one - [Age Lock](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/12583) - which appears to do what you want.

Comment: i have checked any extension that but they are only for restricting content say for registered users only e.t.c

I have tried placing the .htaccess file in the folder containing the template that i am using but that only restricts direct access to that index file. So the index in the root folder fetches all the content, modules and components but the html is all messed up coz it can't access the index that has the markup and the style..

Comment: How about the one I just added to my answer - I typed in "age verification" to the JED search bar and it came straight up.